# SUBSTRING Usage in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, rdbms

Hello I have a query in plsql.
What I am looking for is that when input comes from the server as a parameter in the insert_date_time, I just want to take YYYYMMDD parts.
For example: input 20221116105703603 what I look for is 20221116

I tried this query but couldnt succed I hope you can correct me, thank you.

Note: I defined insert_date_time as NUMBER(17) and in the java code it is defined as String.

```
SELECT insert_date_time FROM oc_vpos.payment_with_link a where a.insert_date_time = substr(:insert_date_time,1,8);
```

Comment: perhaps you might need `trim()` as well such as `substr(trim(:insert_date_time),1,8)`

Comment: please provide sample data and also state the problems that you have currently a dbfiddle would help understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

if `insert_date_time` column's datatype is `date` (should be!), then you'll have to apply `to_date` function with appropriate format model (see line #10):

```
SQL> WITH
  2     payment_with_link (id, insert_date_time)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, DATE '2022-11-16' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 2, DATE '1998-10-23' FROM DUAL)
  7  SELECT insert_date_time
  8    FROM payment_with_link a
  9   WHERE a.insert_date_time =
 10         TO_DATE (SUBSTR ('&insert_date_time', 1, 8), 'yyyymmdd');
Enter value for insert_date_time: 20221116105703603

INSERT_DAT
----------
2022-11-16

SQL>
```

---

Otherwise, if that column's datatype is `varchar2` (or similar `char` *family* data type), then your query should work if the first 8 digits of that column's values match what `substr` function returned.

Comment: it is clearly number as stated in the qiestion

Answer (score 0):

Don't store dates (and times) as strings or numbers, store them as `DATE` or, if you need fractional seconds, `TIMESTAMP` data types.

To convert it to a `TIMESTAMP`, you can use:

```sql
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(insert_date_time), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3')
```

To convert it from a `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` at midnight, you can use:

```sql
TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(insert_date_time), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3'))
```

If you just want the first 8 characters then you can use:

```sql
SUBSTR(insert_date_time, 1, 8)
```

---

For example, given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (insert_date_time NUMBER(17));
INSERT INTO table_name (insert_date_time) VALUES (20221116105703603);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT insert_date_time,
       TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(insert_date_time), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3') AS ts,
       TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(insert_date_time), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3')) AS dt,
       SUBSTR(insert_date_time, 1, 8) AS dt_string
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

| INSERT_DATE_TIME | TS | DT | DT_STRING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20221116105703603 | 2022-11-16 10:57:03.603000000 | 2022-11-16 00:00:00 | 20221116 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oNEfJdjm)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to convert the column to a timestamp, or else you need a lot of conversion

```
CREATE TABLE payment_with_link (insert_date_time Number (17))
```

```
INSERT INTO payment_with_link VALUEs(20221116105703603)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
SELECT insert_date_time FROM payment_with_link a 
  where floor(a.insert_date_time/ 1000000000) = substr('20221116105703603',1,8);
```

| INSERT_DATE_TIME |
| --- |
| 20221116105703603 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j7mqFJwB)